# Why is log4j not behaving as expected?

Tags: configuration, log4j, ibatis

I have a co-worker who is trying to get log4j to behave as follows:

- Log to Stdout
- By default, disable most output
- Show only messages from java.sql.PrepareStatement at level debug and up

He's getting caught up in the 'level' vs 'priority'.  Here is his config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "D:/Java/apache-log4j-1.2.15/src/main/resources/org/apache/log4j/xml/log4j.dtd" >
<log4j:configuration> 

    <!--  Appenders -->
    <appender name="stdout" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%5p %d{ISO8601} [%t][%x] %c - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <!--  Loggers for ibatus and JDBC database -->
    <logger name="java.sql.PreparedStatement">
        <level value="debug"/>
    </logger>

    <!--  The Root Logger -->
    <root>
        <level value="error"/>
        <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Simpler configuration as shown (Root Log Level = ERROR):

```
log4j: reset attribute= "false".
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [java.sql.PreparedStatement] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for java.sql.PreparedStatement is  [debug].
log4j: java.sql.PreparedStatement level set to DEBUG
log4j: Level value for root is  [error].
log4j: root level set to ERROR
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender]
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%5p %d{ISO8601} [%t][%x] %c - %m%n].
log4j: Adding appender named [stdout] to category [root].
```

Configuration with Root Log Level changed to debug (replace queries with …)

```
log4j: reset attribute= "false".
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [java.sql.PreparedStatement] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for java.sql.PreparedStatement is  [debug].
log4j: java.sql.PreparedStatement level set to DEBUG
log4j: Level value for root is  [debug].
log4j: root level set to DEBUG
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender]
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%5p %d{ISO8601} [%t][%x] %c - %m%n].
log4j: Adding appender named [stdout] to category [root].
DEBUG 2010-03-19 12:59:58,256 [main][] com.ibatis.common.jdbc.SimpleDataSource - Created connection 1309601.
DEBUG 2010-03-19 12:59:58,256 [main][] java.sql.Connection - {conn-100000} Connection
DEBUG 2010-03-19 12:59:58,256 [main][] java.sql.Connection - {conn-100000} Preparing Statement:      …
DEBUG 2010-03-19 12:59:58,287 [main][] java.sql.PreparedStatement - {pstm-100001} Executing Statement:      …
DEBUG 2010-03-19 12:59:58,287 [main][] java.sql.PreparedStatement - {pstm-100001} Parameters: [%ATL]
DEBUG 2010-03-19 12:59:58,287 [main][] java.sql.PreparedStatement - {pstm-100001} Types: [java.lang.String]
DEBUG 2010-03-19 12:59:58,366 [main][] java.sql.ResultSet - {rset-100002} ResultSet
DEBUG 2010-03-19 12:59:58,381 [main][] java.sql.ResultSet - {rset-100002} Header: …
DEBUG 2010-03-19 12:59:58,381 [main][] java.sql.ResultSet - {rset-100002} Result: …
DEBUG 2010-03-19 12:59:58,381 [main][] java.sql.ResultSet - {rset-100002} Result: …
DEBUG 2010-03-19 12:59:58,381 [main][] java.sql.ResultSet - {rset-100002} Result: …
DEBUG 2010-03-19 12:59:58,397 [main][] com.ibatis.common.jdbc.SimpleDataSource - Returned connection 1309601 to pool.
```

How does he need to change his log4j.xml config file to make it behave as he's expecting?

Comment: @Martin - Work-around acquired. Not sure why it happens... but Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert the following addition into your log4j.xml:

```
<!-- *******************************************************
     WARNING: iBatus 2.3.3 (only ver. tested) is a little weird. 
             YOU MUST SET
             java.sql.Connection to debug to get any 
             java.sql.PreparedStatement debug logs.
     ************************************************************** -->       
<logger name="java.sql.Connection" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug"/>
</logger>
```

DEBUG 2010-03-19 14:27:08,425 [main][][java.sql.PreparedStatement]  - {pstm-100001} Executing Statement: 

...

Comment: I shamed him into getting an account. I like his username choice.

Answer (score 3):

I looked at the source code for mybatis, shown below.  You have to enable DEBUG on java.sql.Connection in order for it execute the logging for java.sql.PreparedStatement.  I struggled with this all day!

```
private Connection wrapConnection(Connection connection) {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
          return ConnectionLogger.newInstance(connection);
    } else {
      return connection;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason there are no log messages is that code you want to see logs from, doesn't use `java.sql.PrepareStatement` logger, but different loggers. Loggers are usually (although not necessarilly) named after classes that use them. I.e. `com.ibatis.SomeClass` would typically **not** use `java.sql.PrepareStatement` logger.

Set your root logger to DEBUG, and check out names of loggers that give you messages you want. Then configure these loggers with DEBUG and let root log at ERROR level only.

Btw, it's Prepare_d_Statement, it is interface (i.e. no logging code there), and it definitely doesn't use log4j since it is in JDK.

Comment: Can you expand on the second paragraph? It's unclear - how do you set the root logger to DEBUG, and also let the root log at ERROR level only?

Comment: @Kieveli: I meant to use ROOT=DEBUG while configuring logging system, and after you have your loggers set, set ROOT back to ERROR (i.e. not at the same time). I see that iBatis did in fact use **java.sql.PreparedStatement** logger. Was the problem just in the name?

Comment: The cause of the problem is unknown. iBatis' log messages for 'java.sql.PreparedStatement' can only be modified by changing the logger for 'java.sql.Connection'.  This is contrary to log4j, so I can only assume iBatis has done some strange modifications.